# What type of HTTP request does loading an audio file generate?

Tags: html, http

What type of HTTP request does loading an audio file in a browser generate?

For example:

`<audio>
  <source src="<audio location>" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is an HTTP GET request. Same as when loading pretty much every UI component in a browser.